# Customizing charts in qlik sense

Tags: qliksense

I am new to qlik sense, I want to use qlik sense charts but adding some animations to them on loading page, can anyone tell me if that is possible or should I use a custom chart and I can't change the existing one?

In chartjs.org I have seen the full custom charts, but I don't know how to add this customization to the existing chart, not a new chart.